# How to programmatically add an index column for NHibernate Search (Lucene.net) without using FieldAttribute

Tags: nhibernate, search, lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to find out how to programmatically (i.e. without using the `FieldAttribute`) add an index column for NHibernate Search (Lucene.net).

I'm having inheritance issues due to the fact that the `FieldAttribute` is not automatically inherited.

The following code illustrates what I want to do.

```
class A
{
    [Field(Index.Tokenized)]
    public virtual string P1
    {
        get
        {
            return "P1";
        }
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string P1
    {
        get
        {
            return "P1+";
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the override of P1 to be indexed but it didn't. When I inspected the `FieldAttribute` class, I found that it didn't have `Inherited = true` specified in the `AttributeUsage` attribute.

I then added a `FieldAttribute` to the overridden property but that resulted in NHibernate Search bailing out with an exception stating that an item with the same key has already been added to a dictionary. I figure that's because there's two equally named properties both with a `FieldAttribute` on them in the type chain and it accepts only one.

So, how do I programmatically solve this by not using `FieldAttribute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-attribute mapping was recently implemented, take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.ashmind.com/index.php/2009/10/26/custom-mapping-for-nhibernate-search/).

Comment: Great, I didn't catch that edit but I'm delighted to see that patch got in!

Answer (score 1):

I've just started a Fluent NHibernate.Search mapping interface similar to FluentNHibarnate, which allow you to map your entities without attributes.

```
public class BookSearchMap : DocumentMap<Book>
{
    public BookSearchMap()
    {
        Id(p => p.BookId).Field("BookId").Bridge().Guid();
        Name("Book");
        Boost(500);
        Analyzer<StandardAnalyzer>();

        Map(x => x.Title)
            .Analyzer<StandardAnalyzer>()
            .Boost(500);

        Map(x => x.Description)
            .Boost(500)
            .Name("Description")
            .Store().Yes()
            .Index().Tokenized();
    }
}
```

You should take a look on the project site hosted on codeplex.

http://fnhsearch.codeplex.com/